# Problema con modulo en Nosetests, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando ejecutar mis test (realizados con python 3.5), meidante nosetests, pero al hacerlo con el comando `nosetests` me sale lo siguiente

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named 'www')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 79, in importFromDir
    fh, filename, desc = find_module(part, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named 'www'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

El problema está que en mi proyecto no tengo ningún modulo que se llame así, y no encuentro que haya uno de Nosetests.

Al ejecutar mis test por separado, funcionan perfecto, pero cuando lo hago mediante nosetests es el problema.

El encabezado de los test es así:

`from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
  import time 
  import unittest 
  from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 
  class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase): 
   (definicion de funciones)
  obj = LoginTest() 
  obj.test()`

Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostrar tus pruebas?

Comment: Ahí edité la pregunta con parte del código de los test, pero no creo que el problema esté ahí, porque los ejecuto en mi pc local y funciona pero el problema lo tengo en el servidor (nginx en google compute engine)